# Batch FOR command the ECHO command only show the last line of the output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use FOR command to get PROCESS ID of a programs which is running multiple times. When I use the following command I can see 3 PID

`C:\>wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID | findstr [0-9]`

**output:**
c:>

> 396
>
> 13928
>
> 20424

but when I use this in same command in FOR command I only get echo output of last PID 20424 only. I am trying to search the PID of notepad.exe(or anyother program) open and see if it is used in procdump command, if not I want to execute procdump with the new PID.

**Script**

```
@echo on
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%x in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9] ^|find /v /c "notepad.exe"') do set myPID=%%x
echo %myPID%

:loop1
if /I %myPID% geq 0 (
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do set nPID=%%a 
 echo %nPID%
 echo nPID %npid%
 for /f "tokens=8" %%b in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='procdump.exe'" get CommandLine ^| findstr %npid%') do (
  set dpid=%%b
  echo dPID %dpid%
  if %npid% neq %dpid% (
   start /B C:\Users\RV017019\Downloads\Procdump\procdump -c 1 -s 5 -n 5 %npid%
   )
  )
 )
 goto :loop1
)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\>for /F "TOKENS=1" %x in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID | findstr [0-9] |find /v /c "note
pad.exe"') do set myPID=%x

C:\>set myPID=3

C:\>echo 3
3

C:\>if /I 3 GEQ 0 (
for /F "TOKENS=1" %a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID | findstr [0-9]') do set nPID=%a
 echo 20424
```

*** you can see it is picking up the last PID**

```
 if 20424 EQU 396 (echo "you are right" 20424  )  else (echo "Not right" )
 goto :loop1
)

C:\>set nPID=396

C:\>set nPID=13928

C:\>set nPID=20424
20424
"Not right"

C:\>if /I 3 GEQ 0 (
for /F "TOKENS=1" %a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID | findstr [0-9]') do set nPID=%a
 echo 20424
 if 20424 EQU 396 (echo "you are right" 20424  )  else (echo "Not right" )
 goto :loop1
)

C:\>set nPID=396

C:\>set nPID=13928

C:\>set nPID=20424
20424
"Not right"
```

I want for each PID and search for procdump command if it is not there i execute a new procdump command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tries I was able to pull this script which is able to do what I wanted. If someone can help improve, that will be awesome.- Thanks

```
@echo off

for /f "TOKENS=1" %%x in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='firstnet.exe'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9] ^|find /v /c "firstnet.exe"') do set myPID=%%x
echo %myPID%

:loop1
if %myPID% geq 0 (

FOR /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='firstnet.exe'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do (
set /A npid=%%a
call:test %%a

)
goto :loop1
)
exit /b

:test
  for /f "tokens=8" %%b in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='procdump.exe'" get CommandLine ^| findstr %npid%') do set ppid=%%b
if [%1] EQU [] ( set ppid=00 ECHO Value Missing
 )
  if /I %npid% NEQ %ppid% ( 
  start procdump -c 10 -n 100 -s 3 %npid%
    ) ELSE (
  echo THIS PID %npid% PROCDUMP RUNNING
  )
timeout /t 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the echo into the `for`statement (you will have to use delayed expansion):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%x in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9] ^|find /v /c "notepad.exe"') do (
  set myPID=%%x
  echo !myPID!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID  ^|findstr [0-9]') do (
    call:test %%a)
exit/b

:test
echo Testing PID : %1
if %1==396 echo Do  something with %1
if %1==13928 echo Do  something with %1
if %1==20424 echo Do  something with %1
```

Comment: 396 13928 and 20424 are result of the command. These numbers can change depending on the program is close or new program has started.

Comment: I now that ! It's just an example that get all the PIDs. What are you trying to test ????

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get each individual PID:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%x in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessID /format:htable ^| find "<div" ') do call :label "%%x"
pause
goto :EOF
:label
echo %~1
```